# Function accepting rvalue reference, how to use it twice if order is unspecified

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Imagine a function accepting a rvalue reference that it can move from. If the function needs to use that object multiple times, the last usage can take advantage of the rvalue reference and can `std::move` from that.

```cpp
void tripple(std::string&& str) {
    std::vector<std::string> vector;
    vector.push_back(str); // invokes 'const std::string&', will copy
    vector.push_back(str); // invokes 'const std::string&', will copy
    vector.push_back(std::move(str)); // invokes 'std::string&&', will move
}
```

But what if the order of operation is *indeterminately sequenced*

> 15. In a function call, value computations and side effects of the initialization of every parameter are indeterminately sequenced with respect to value computations and side effects of any other parameter.

So for example

```
void foo(std::string&& str) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;
    map.try_emplace(str, str); // will copy key and emplace the value from copy of str

    // any of those three shouldn't be valid
    map.try_emplace(std::move(str), str);
    map.try_emplace(str, std::move(str));
    map.try_emplace(std::move(str), std::move(str));
}
```

Is the only option to use at least one move by explicitly making a copy and moving both as

```
void foo(std::string&& str) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;
    std::string copy = str;

    map.try_emplace(std::move(copy), std::move(str)); // ok, two moves
}
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: How about copy it manually and move both? E.g. `string str2 = str; try_emplace(move(str),move(str2));`

Comment: Last sample can be simplified to `map.try_emplace(std::string(str), std::move(str));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is absolutely correct.

If you do it like you described it, you will not get issues. But every case is individual. The designers of the standard library foreseen this case and made two overloads:

```
template< class... Args >
pair<iterator, bool> try_emplace( const Key& k, Args&&... args );  // (1)

template< class... Args >
pair<iterator, bool> try_emplace( Key&& k, Args&&... args );       // (2)
```

In this particular case no explicit copy is required, you can call without any issue

```
void foo(std::string&& str) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;

    map.try_emplace(str, std::move(str)); // ok, (1) is used.
}
```

Note, `str` is l-value, is reference to r-value, `std::move(str)` performs nothing except typecasting l-value to r-value reference.

[Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace#Notes)

> Unlike `insert` or `emplace`, these functions do not move from rvalue arguments if the insertion does not happen, which makes it easy to manipulate maps whose values are move-only types, such as `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<foo>>`. In addition, `try_emplace` treats the key and the arguments to the `mapped_type` separately, unlike `emplace`, which requires the arguments to construct a `value_type` (that is, a `std::pair`).

Comment: But `try_emplace` might construct value before key, so "moved" key.

Comment: @Jarod42 Look at [Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace#Notes).

Comment: *"if the insertion does not happen"*, but order is not stipulated when insertion **does** happen.

Comment: @Jarod42 Which constructor of `std::pair`  or `std::make_pair` will construct the second before the first member taking into account `const std::string&` as the first parameter?

Comment: So it goes to trusting the implementation, as it's (`std::pair` constructor order of operation) not standardized. Fair enough.

Comment: @S.M.: `typename <typename T1, typename T2>class pair {T2 second; T1 first; /*constructors*/};` seems legit, even if strange. (or circumvoluted constructors).

Comment: @Jarod42, do you mean that even if the first overload of `try_emplace` is used, the parameter `args` could be move constructed from the argument `std::move(str)` causing the first parameter `k` to reference a moved-from argument `str`?

Comment: @Enlico: parameters are aliasing each other, so even if `k` is a const ref, it can be modified by its alias. So if `args` is changed (by `move` constructor) before `k` is used, then `k` would already be moved.

Comment: @Jarod42, and if the overload was taking by `Key` instead of `const Key&`, the problem would still be there, right?

Comment: @Enlico: if Key is used by value, then we fallback to last OP sample (which is ok). Inside `try_emplace`, parameters don't alias, so as soon as parameters are correct, we are fine. As `std::move` is just a cast, `try_emplace(std::string(str), std::move(str))` would be fine (copy key).